# Basement Sub-panel Breaker Size

Tags: subpanel

I am confused about small-appliance branch circuit for service load calculation.  I am trying to size my breaker for a sub-panel in my basement from my main 200A panel.

I will have a main room, wet bar area, bedroom, and bathroom.

I have calculated the following loads:

- Lighting Wattage = 790sq ft x  3 = 2,370 VA
- Under counter 46 Bottle Wine Cooler: 90VA
- Under counter refrigerator: 240VA
- HVAC Heat Pump = 4,320 VA
- HVAC Air Handler = 960 VA
- HVAC Heat Strips = 4,800 VA
- Sump Pump = 1,200 VA

Do I need to consider any small-appliance branch circuits in my calculation?

Comment: The heat pump and heat strips do not need to both be counted, since their design precludes both being on at once.

Comment: @Harper -- not necessarily -- under low ambient conditions where the pump is short capacity, the compressor may be going full bore while the heat strips cycle to make up the difference

Answer (score 1):

The small appliance requirement is for the kitchen counters 2 as 20 amp circuits. If you want you can add a circuit for the bar but it would not be required.

Comment: Thanks.  I was going to have one GFCI circuit serve the bar counter and the bathroom.  So would this add 1,500 VA to my total load?

Comment: The bathroom usually requires a dedicated circuit for the lighting and outlets unless going to a second bathroom. 210.11.c.3 in the nec

Comment: Thanks, understand.  So the wet bar circuit and dedicated bathroom circuits will count as 2 small appliance requirement (2X1,500)? Or these do not affect the total load for the service load calculation?

Comment: Thanks.  Adding in 2x1,500 for the small appliance circuits I am calculating a total load of 65 amps.

Comment: The loads count in addition to the required circuit for each bathroom and the 2 for the kitchen small appliance. If you are doing a whole house calc the laundry also requires a circuit. There are some handy online calculators that may help they ask the basics but include the required minimum size branch circuits code requires. I just found one. @ nojolt.com/load/calculations.shtml I have not used it just the first one I found.  If you don't want to figure every outlet use 1va per square foot for the outlet load other than the above required bath,kitchen,& laundry.

Comment: Thanks. Adding in 2x1,500 for the small appliance circuits I am calculating a total load of 65 amps.    General Lighting Load = 2,370 VA.  Small branch circuits = 3,000 VA. Lighting load demand factors: a) First 3000 or less at 100% = 3,000 VA b) From 3001 to 120,000 at 35% = 830.  So total Lighting Demand Load = 3,830 VA.  Space heating and air conditioning Load = 8,937 VA.  Appliance load = 1,290 VA, Motor Loads = 1,200 VA + (25% of largest motor load)  300 VA = 1,500 VA.  TOTAL CALCULATED DEMAND = 15,556 VA or 65 AMPS.

Comment: I am wondering if I should go with a 70AMP breaker or go with a 100AMP breaker (future proof).

Comment: You can use the larger load of AC or heat don't have to use both but I would go with a 100 amp, but I always go larger than needed. I have redone 1 customer's sub 3 times in about 15 years he kept telling me I can't afford it the first time and the second when installing a 100 amp on the 3rd time he asked me why this time I wasent saying to go larger (this was the size I suggested the first time) any larger and his main panel would need to be upgraded so he ended up paying 3x of doing it a bit bigger the first time, so go big with the feeder 100 amp larger with the panel for extra slots.

Comment: Thank you Ed for your advice.  I am going to use a 100A breaker.